# Can't make code_ownership and code_teams gems to work

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

The gems [code_teams](https://github.com/rubyatscale/code_teams/), [code_ownership](https://github.com/rubyatscale/code_ownership/) should allow one to tag files/whole folders by team name but after adding them to my project, running bundle install etc, I still encounter the same error

```
Passed `nil` into T.must
```

sample team file (placed in config/teams as advised) is as following

```
name: Smurfs
owned_globs:
  - folder/folder2/**/*
```

The code where I try to use the info is :

```
x = CodeOwnership.for_backtrace(e.backtrace)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the path was not in the format expected.

The path should not end with /*